# How to enable Azure Access Control for my WCF Service

Tags: .net, authentication, azure, cloud

This [article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-dotnet-how-to-use-access-control/)

I was following above guide. The management have changed since it was written it seems, as i cant find "Click the Service Bus, Access Control & Caching tab."

I have been reading abit up and got to the conclussion that i should create an Active Directory on Azure to add some access control in my RESTful Servicve. Now i cant find out how to enable/use it.

Any advice on how to continue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're using the new (preview) portal which doesn't support managing ACS just yet. By hovering the green Preview button on top of the page you can choose to switch back to the old portal where you can manage ACS:

[image]

Alternatively, use the direct URL to the portal: http://windows.azure.com

Comment: Bonus Info: The url takes me to the new portal no matter what. No hover menu shows up in Chrome. So when you told me it was there and i vent in IE and looked it worked :) Only used half a day trying to find alternative ways to do authentication. THanks.